# How do I get the Android Kindle/nook apps to recognize .MOBI/.EPUB files on my SD card?

Tags: nook-for-android, kindle-for-android

I prefer to manage my ebook files manually, so I'm having trouble getting the Android Kindle and nook apps to locate the .MOBI and .EPUB files that I put on my SD card.

Is there any sort of Browse feature in these apps for locating custom ebook files?

For the moment, I'm getting around this issue by using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)/[FBReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd), but I'd rather use plain drag & drop and the official Kindle/nook apps if possible.

Comment: Do you want the **Kindle** (or **Nook**) app. to look at the correct location, by modifying the app. setup? (path to external is device/model specific)  **OR**, an app. to *move* the files from the (external) micro-SD to default path (in internal flash) for each app.?

Comment: I'd prefer to drag & drop ebook files onto a single directory that all my ereaders see, but they each use a different autorecognition directory, instead of, for example, `/mnt/sdcard/Download`.

Comment: Why two different ebook filetypes?  If they are DRM controlled, then you can *only* view them under the correct viewer.  If not, you should just use **Calibre** (on Windows, Ubuntu, etc.) to convert ALL to your preferred e-book filetype.

Comment: @david6 Calibre is bloody awesome. I guess you would have to assume that to some strange user, maintaining their original file's current formats and pathnames are more important than say, convenience.

Comment: Still puzzled, by what you are trying to solve ..

Comment: I wanted to find out where the various ereader apps looked for / stored ebooks on Android. Because most of the silly apps fail to include a manual filetree Browse feature.

Answer (score 1):

Mirrored on [gist](https://gist.github.com/3954528).

Custom ebook files can be read on Android devices by employing a collection of software, detailed below.

Both Android and iOS devices can simply use [iBooks](http://www.apple.com/ipad/built-in-apps/) or [Stanza](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stanza/id284956128?mt=8), and connect to [Calibre](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#how-do-i-use-app-with-my-ipad-iphone-itouch).

A more manual method employes [Astro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) for browsing Android files manually. For any ebook file format, if an appropriate app is installed, Astro will be able to open the ebook. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_e-book_reader_software#File_formats_supported) for a table of ereaders vs ebook file formats supported.

Secondary software will be required to actually get the ebook files onto the mobile device:

## [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/products/mobile/android.html)

## [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/mobile)

Each ereader app looks for books in a different directory. A good compromise is to store all ebooks in `/mnt/sdcard/Books`, organizing ebooks at will through folder hierarchies, and using Astro to navigate to and open individual ebooks.

## [FBReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd)

- Autorecognition: `/mnt/sdcard/Books`
- Custom browsing: `FBReader library -> File tree`

## [Kindle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd)

- Autorecognition: `/mnt/sdcard/Kindle`

## [nook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bn.ereader&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd)

- Autorecognition: `/mnt/sdcard/Nook/MyDocuments`

## [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd)

- Autorecognition: `/mnt/sdcard/Download/Adobe Reader`
- Custom browsing: `Documents -> All PDFs -> Folder View`

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy S5 running v5.0 (Lollipop), the Kindle app refuses to read books you drop into the SD card. There is a folder in the internal memory named "Books" which both the Kindle app and Nook app will read from (including PDFs).